# How can I overlay an image on an element without creating an image element?

Tags: html, css

So let's say I have an HTML structure like

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>Here's a headline</h1>
        <p>Here's some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Blah blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want the gif https://www.wpfaster.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/loading-gif.gif to overlay the entire thing when the class `loading` is added to `outer`. Is there a way to do this with pseudo-elements? Problem with adding a `background-image` is that it's behind the inner elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be pretty close to what you are looking for. Might need to tweak background color.

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.outer.loading:before {
  background: #fefefe url('https://www.wpfaster.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/loading-gif.gif') center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/ac5jr5nq/

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
.loading .inner { visibility: hidden; }
```

```css
.loading {
  background-image: url('https://www.wpfaster.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/loading-gif.gif');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}

.loading .inner { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>Here's a headline</h1>
        <p>Here's some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Blah blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="$('.outer').toggleClass('loading')">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Oh... I like this. I didn't even think about hiding the content to make the background visible. +1